# Flutter : How to set maxLine in Text widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to set maximum 2 line in my Text widget and also need to set "..."(ellipse) at the end of line

```
Container(
     height: 100,
     alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
     child: Text("${news.newsDetails}"),
 )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `maxLines` and `overflow`

```
    Text(
     '${model.title}',
     maxLines: 2,
     overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
 ),
```